# Displaying chart data from a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, highcharts

Im following the instructions in http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database to display some data comming from a database using php PDO and mysql but i only get slices when i show the chart.. this is my code

MODEL

```
  public function get_proyectos_service_por_id($idproject) {

    $sql = "SELECT p.id_project, s.service_type, s.completion_status, s.id_service, sp.id_projectserv

    FROM projects p
    LEFT JOIN project_serv sp ON p.id_project = sp.id_project
    LEFT JOIN services s ON sp.id_service = s.id_service 
    WHERE p.id_project = ?";

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $idproject, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = array();

    foreach( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ){ 

     $rows[] = array("service" =>$row['service_type'], "status" =>$row['completion_status']); 

 } 

 return $rows;
}

 // Now i call this method

 $project = new Proyecto();
 $serv = $project->get_proyectos_service_por_id($pro);
```

// This is the output with the JS

```
$(function () {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'chart_div',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Datos de proyecto'
                    },

                    series: [{
                        data: [<?php echo implode(",", $serv); ?>]

                    }]
                };
                new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
            });
```

Comment: why you just don't use json_encode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please familair with article about preprocessing data http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing , you can also use json_encode()

Comment: What procude your <?php echo implode(",", $serv); ?> ? Why you cannot use json_encode? like <?php echo json_encode($serv); ?>

Comment: Anyway could you attach what echo implode(",", $serv); print ? because problem is with parsing string to number (highcharts use number data) or incorrect series structure

Comment: If i echo out implode(",", $serv); i get Array,Array.. If i var_dump($serv); i get array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["service"]=> string(16) "Reparacion 60kVA" ["status"]=> string(1) "2" } [1]=> array(2) { ["service"]=> string(17) "Mantenimiento Gen" ["status"]=> string(1) "4" } }

Comment: Guess the problem might be with parsing string to number however i've changed to this: array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["service"]=> string(16) "Reparacion 60kVA" ["status"]=> int(2) } [1]=> array(2) { ["service"]=> string(17) "Mantenimiento Gen" ["status"]=> int(4) } }
and i still see nothing just slices

Comment: As I mentioned you need to numbers, morever highcharts needs to x/y parameters, not customised names as you have. like (status).