# Displaying the data in the text field from my query in database php pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo, textbox

i have made a connection to database i also was able to make a search query then i stumble upon this problem.how to show/display those data in the textfield/inputfield.

i have read in some source like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024952/how-to-retrieve-the-data-from-mysql-database-and-put-it-into-textfield-and-texta) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181462/displaying-chart-data-from-a-database) but unfortunately they dont provide the answer and looking for any suggestions are appreciated.

***UPDATE***
i want to show display the data from php query if possible i mean after query i will show data if there are available if none nothing will show

```
    if(!empty($_POST['upcomingeventwhat'])){
            $upcomingeventwhat = trim($_POST['upcomingeventwhat']);

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_what = ? ") ;
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$upcomingeventwhat);
            $stmt->execute();
            $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //$data = $stmt->fetch();
            if($selected_row){
                echo $selected_row['event_what'];
                echo $selected_row['event_where'];
                echo $selected_row['event_when'];
                echo $selected_row['event_who'];
       ***

//make this echo show in the textfield in html
    //example i have this text field in html
    //<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwho" maxlength="50"

*** 
            }else{
                echo "No event found";
            }
        }else{
            echo "what is empty";    
        }
```

Comment: @SKRocks i havent started to any since i have no idea how to display i all i have is the query

Comment: see some links may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183579/pdo-get-data-from-database

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/

Answer (score 0):

ok i got your problem simple do it

```
echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwhat" maxlength="50" value="'.$selected_row['event_what'].'"> ';

echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwhere" maxlength="50" value="'.$selected_row['event_where'].'"> ';

echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwhen" maxlength="50" value="'.$selected_row['event_when'].'"> ';

echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwho" maxlength="50" value="'.$selected_row['event_who'].'"> ';
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
$event_what = "";
$event_where ="";
$event_when ="";
$event_who ="";
// set above variable blank first

if(!empty($_POST['upcomingeventwhat'])){
            $upcomingeventwhat = trim($_POST['upcomingeventwhat']);

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_what = ? ") ;
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$upcomingeventwhat);
            $stmt->execute();
            $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //$data = $stmt->fetch();
            if($selected_row){
                $event_what = $selected_row['event_what'];
                $event_where = $selected_row['event_where'];
                $event_when = $selected_row['event_when'];
                $event_who = $selected_row['event_who'];

                 // assign them database value  

            }else{
                echo "No event found";
            }
        }else{
            echo "what is empty";    
        }

// now you can use that variables in textfield value like below

echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwhat" maxlength="50" value="'.$event_what.'"> ';

    echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwhere" maxlength="50" value="'.$event_where.'"> ';

    echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwhen" maxlength="50" value="'.$event_when.'"> ';

    echo '<input  type="text" name="upcomingeventwho" maxlength="50" value="'.$event_who.'"> ';
```

Comment: i see so i need to put this in html..for example no data is available will it be blank?

Comment: no first set some variable for it blank and assign database value to them and use that variable in your textfield see update 2

Comment: you mean this is code is for html?then i have to write a variable with null value first then assign the database value to it so it will show the data?

Comment: ya see updated answer